# Hierarchy Visualization in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a requirements to create a Hierarchy Visualization in Spotfire. I search from the net but didn't get anything nearest from my requirements. It is possible to achieve this in Spotfire or there is any other option to do this chart. thanks.

Currently my Spotfire version is 7.0.

Hierarchy Visualization Sample:
[image]

Comment: Per niko, if you upgrade/get access to JSViz, you could use Google Charts for this. They have a lovely Org chart which would probably work for you: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

Comment: How can I add those Google charts in Spotfire? as well as the value for every rectangle.

Comment: I can access  the JSviz from the spotfire. This is my first time to use JSviz. not familiar on how to use this.

Comment: I got it. I have to open the properties then go to library then embedded content to inject the file.

Comment: Spotfire has a ton of Sample reports that can help as well. I think they primarily use D3 but its similar: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/javascript-visualization-framework-jsviz-and-tibco-spotfire

Answer (score 2):

there is no hierarchy visualization in Spotfire.

you can talk to your TIBCO account rep about the JSViz extension, however, which would allow you to use D3 to create one.

honestly I would suggest to look for a software that provides an org chart like Visio or [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/). this isn't really a data visualization as much as it is a diagram.

Comment: I try to draw a sample  rectangle but could not figure out on how to load or add this in spotfire as well as the value for every rectangle.

Comment: this is not a level of support I can really provide over SO. if you'd like to talk about a professional services engagement with TIBCO, you can reach out to me via email (check my profile). please reference this question in your message.

Answer (score 0):

If this is static you could probably create it using html and css, and maybe even use sparklines to add some dynamic text if you need to

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple options to visualize this in Spotfire.
However, if you intend to create as shown in image, I would suggest Text Area to do it.
First, you would need to organize data as in the format you want to show, parent and then child and then child. You would have to then make a HTML table in the text area.
Based on your parent id, you make a row with TR tag and as you keep getting child keep adding it further to the HTML as  TR. Values you can use calculated values to show or document properties to simply display. You would need to play with HTML in this case.

The above description that I am giving is to be entirely performed in IronPython. Only thing tricky here is calculated values which you will have to put in HTMl. Instead of creating a dynamic element I would suggest giving  Dynamic value in HTMl itself using document properties.